# Is there a way to reduce the time for the snowpipe load time?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-pipe

I'm reading this [User Guide](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html#continuous-data-loads-i-e-snowpipe-and-file-sizing) and it mentions that "typically" snowpipe takes 1 minute to load the data. In my experiments I found that it takes a minute always. Where is this 1 minute latency coming from? It feels like there is some batch processing going on per minute. Is there a setting somewhere to reduce it further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, there's no setting to reduce this latency - you're essentially microbatching to the minute by minute level.

If you want to do more frequent updates, your best option is to keep a warehouse running and either submit `UPDATE` or `COPY` queries to it.

If you don't require sub-minute latency, you should use Snowpipe and potentially a tool like Kinesis Firehose to batch up records into a single file that drops into S3 once per minute.